# be J be a matrix so: JJ^-1 = I and A a matrix so: A^t JA = J. prove that A is invertible so that AA^-1 = I

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

be J be a matrix so: $JJ^{-1}$ = I and A a matrix so: $A^tJA^ = J$. prove that A can invertible so that $AA^{-1} = I$

the big question here is: what are the properties of A transpose, that allows solving this question.

please don't solve directly, give hints :)

Comment: This is a little weird: $\;A^{-1}\;$ *already* appears in the info given, so what's there to prove??

Comment: Indeed. Yotam, are you sure the problem is stated exactly as it was given to you?

Comment: fixed. sorry about that it was A without ^-1 and changed it to invertible

Comment: Do you know about determinants?

Comment: not yet... but explain, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A^tJA=J\implies A^t\left(JAJ^{-1}\right)=JJ^{-1}=I$$

Now watch closely at $\;\left(JAJ^{-1}\right)^t\;$ .

**Added:**

Using associativity of matrix multiplication, you can also begin with

$$A^tJA=J\implies J^{-1}(A^tJA)=(J^{-1}A^tJ)A=J^{-1}J=I$$

and etc.

Comment: I deleted my comment as not to ruin your intent. But I think focusing on the matrix you suggest is taking a step in the wrong direction which can do more harm than good. Even if you want the OP to work a bit for himself, I don't think it is a good idea to make him work by taking him to the wrong place.

Comment: Why wrong place, @GitGud ? I think using the basic properties of the transpose wrt original matrix is more or less pretty basic, but taking into account your comment I will add something very close to your comment in order to give the OP an alternative. Thank you.

Comment: I must be missing your intent in focusing on that matrix, but never mind, I trust you enough to not care that I don't see it. **Edit:** After the edit I feel comfortable up voting.

Comment: I am missing some property of the transpose. i just get completely stuck

Comment: No property of the transpose is being used. It might perhaps be clearer if the order of the first two items in the last string of equalities were interchanged.

Comment: @Timbuc, why don't you multiply by $J$ on the left so that $JA^tJ$ is the inverse of $A.$

Comment: @abel, because we don't know wheter $\;J^2=I\;$ ...

Comment: @Timbuc, i should have written multiply by $J^{-1}$ on the left. my bad.

Comment: @abel, Ok...and that's precisely what I did some 3 and something hours ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the [multiplicative property of determinants](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Multiplicativity_and_matrix_groups), and the connection of the determinant [with invertibility](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem).

Comment: could you please elaborate? my studies are not in English so the terms are not clear to me.

Comment: @YotamAlon Change the wikipedia language to one if you comfortable with. The links are right there. Anyway, didn't you say you don't know about determinants?

Comment: @YotamAlon if you know that the determinant obeys $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ and that a matrix over a field is invertible iff it has nonzero determinant, you can solve this.

Comment: @GitGud oop, I did not see the comment claiming not to know determinants when I started writing. It is very odd, if true.

Comment: I'm just shooting in all directions, in hopes of hitting it (if the metaphor was ok)

Comment: @YotamAlon, by your name I' making an educated guess you're israeli: multiplicative property of determinants = משפט המכפלה לדטרמיננטות, inveritibility =להיות הפיכה . By the way, you will need english a lot pretty soon if you{re studying sciences and-or computation, so you better begin learning all these terms.

Comment: @rschwieb I didn't mean to criticize, in fact there has been a recent meta question regarding answers beyond the askers ability, and the consensus is that it is OK.

Comment: @GitGud, and a rather important part of that problem you mention is that usually one doesn't know what the asker's abilities are, as there is no place where asked have to input their level, prior studies and etc.